# How to use globs to not do an action on a file? (Gulp)

Tags: regex, node.js, gulp, gulp-if

I'm using gulp with gulp-if, gulp-babel, and gulp-uglify, my intent is to not run babel or uglify on minified JS files since the minified files are all lib/vendor files that don't need to be processed. However, they do need to be moved over into the new folder.

Here's what I've got:

```
.pipe($.if(!/(.min.js)/g,
  $.babel({
     presets: ['es2015']
  })
 ))
.pipe($.if(!/(.min.js)/g,
   $.uglify()
))
```

I don't think the rest of the context is too important, so I left it out.

The issue that I'm having currently is that the expression isn't working, I guess I wasn't clear on the syntax of how gulp-if works.

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to figure it out..

I replaced `.pipe($.if(/.min.js/g,` with `.pipe($.if(match,`

Then created the match function..

```
function match(file) {
    if (file.path.match(/.min.js/g)) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Now it works as expected!

Please let me know if there is an easier/better way to do this!

Comment: Easier/better way: `.pipe($.if('!**/*.min.js',`

Comment: @SvenSchoenung I believe you and will try this but I thought I tried that In the first place and it didn't work as expected